# VB.NET generics to C# syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, generics

Could you please show me the C# Equivalent of this VB.NET code:

```
Public Partial Class Index
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Viewpage(Of List(Of Task))


End Class
```

I am not sure where/how to add it in for C#:

```
public partial class DirList : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{

}
```

The code is suppose to tell the class to expect a list of tasks from the controller...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public partial class DirList : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Task>>
{

}
```