# Tips for moving a large project from VB.Net to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, translation

I have been tasked with moving a rather large project from VB.Net to C#. Are there any converters, and if so what should I watch for? Are there areas of the code that are known to be problem areas during a conversion like this (Data Access Layer, etc..)

Comment: Why would you want to? You can use C# code in a VB.NET app. Why go through the trauma of conversion?

Comment: I was going to comment the same way, but I figured they must have a reason (like harder to find VB.NET developers?)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Why not legacy the VB code, and slowly migrate to C#. VB.Net maintenance shouldn't be that arduous, since it's so close to C# in terms of runtime anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Please see these SO posts:

- [Good way to convert VB.Net to C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756590/good-way-to-convert-vb-net-to-c)
- [Convert VB.NET —> C# Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355340/convert-vb-net-c-projects)
- [What is the best C# to VB.net converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88359/what-is-the-best-c-to-vb-net-converter)
- [Converting vb.net to c# tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57473/converting-vb-net-to-c-tips)
- [VB.NET generics to C# syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189954/vb-net-generics-to-c-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

There's an open source C#/VB.net IDE called SharpDevelop that has a converter to convert from VB.net to C# and C# to VB.net.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of required patience is proportional to the size of the project.